# How To Create a Simple RestLet(Hello World) in Nestuite and how to pass to external system

Tags: javascript, netsuite

Plss try to explain me step by step if possible. You send me directly to my mail **Thanks**. Let me come back with awesome explanation

Thanks,
Regina

Comment: Welcome to SO,Please provide your code or anything you ve tried  :)

Comment: I have not tried any thing yet,one thing i want to send that "hello world" to dell bhoomi .

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you want to "host" a Restlet on Netsuite and have it send back "Hello World".

I'm not sure if you've figured out the creating a script on Netsuite first and deploy it etc... 
But if you've figured out all that here is just the snippet you need:

```
/**
@NApiVersion 2.x
@NModuleSc​o​p​e Public
@NScriptType Restlet
*/

define([], function() {
  function getRecord(context) {
    return { msg: 'hello World' };
  }

  return {
    get: getRecord
  };
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Here you go:

[Restlet Example: Hello World](https://ursuscode.com/public/netsuitehelp/section_4628875570.html)